# One Array function using INDEX, SMALL, IF works but the other doesn't

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm hoping someone can figure this out for me, because I'm stumped!

I have an excel tab called **Data**, that is holding all the data I want to look at.

| Check (A) | Sector (B) | Sub/Sector(C) | Overarching Question (D) | Q# (E) | Questions (F) | BHA_Tool (G) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | S1 | Sector:A | Is this a new methodology, tool, or technique related to agricultural production? | S1q1 | Is this a new methodology, tool, or technique related to agricultural production? | 6 Other Source |
| True | S1 | Sector:A | Do the targeted participants have experience in the proposed activity? | S1q2 | What are the types of post-production processes your household currently utilizes | 3 FGD - Pop |
| True | S1 | Sector:A | Do the targeted participants have experience in the proposed activity? | S1q3 | What are the types of grain storage your household currently uses | 3 FGD - Pop |

Table of data in DATA tab

In tab **Full_Questions** I query data using the following array:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!F$2:F$300,SMALL(IF(Data!A$2:A$300=TRUE,ROW(Data!F$2:F$300)),ROW(1:1))-1,1),"")}
```

And it works fine.

| Full List of Q (A) | To Be asked of... (B) | Available in tool.. (C) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Is this a new methodology, tool, or technique related to agricultural production? | Project Documents | 6 Other Source |
| What are the types of post-production processes your household currently utilizes | Farming Households; disag by gender, age range, etc | 3 FGD - Pop |
| What are the types of grain storage your household currently uses | Farming Households; disag by gender, age range, etc | 3 FGD - Pop |

Table of data in Full_Questions, which is queried from Data tab by either an array (column A) or INDEX MATCH (columns B and C)

On the next tab: **FGD - Pop**, I try to narrow down the data using the following array formula:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Full_Questions!A$2:A$300,SMALL(IF(Full_Questions!C$2:C$300="3 FGD - Pop",ROW(Full_Questions!A$2:A$300)),ROW(1:1))-1,1),"")}
```

But I don't get anything back.

I thought it could be that I can't query data with an array from another array so I tried:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!F$2:F$300,SMALL(IF(AND(Data!A$2:A$300=TRUE,Data!G$2:G$300="3 FGD - Pop"),ROW(Data!F$2:F$300)),ROW(1:1))-1,1),"")}
```

But that also didn't work.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like the second formula is returning errors.

Comment: You third formula will fail due `AND(...)` function. Put some sample data here as text table so that we can copy then explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @SJR yes, if I remove the IFERROR, it returns the error #VALUE!

Comment: @Harun24HR Ugh, I tried to upload data but am at a loss as to how to do it. Are there any clear instructions on this? I'm happy to upload. But why would the AND make the function fail? Is that not allowed for an array?

Answer (score 1):

Trim the "FGD - Pop" field / data (at source and in the respective function"

*Context*

I'm not allowed to say "*I like the function construct you've used - i.e. the combination of index/small etc. to bring back unique index/match results - great initiative*" because it'll be edited out on account of not being 'robotic' enough in our replies (so will repeat this self-same sentiment in my comment below - ha!).

*Actions*

I've replicated all of your inputs / functions in [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18dHCe9v59O6z4xHoab6TTLCpAhYR9C2deIoILEfFIaU/edit?usp=sharing) google workbook (filled in the lookup on Pop-3g in Full_Questions too, which I believe would've been sourced from the Data tab in the first instance. Anyways.

Upon doing this (and fixing up the small issues re: extra spaces - e.g. present in the FGD-Pop data), I get your function working fine in the FGD-Pop tab.

I've also included a slightly quicker/easier way to achieve what you've done using the filter function red font).

*Results*

Screenshots refer to the relevant functions if you've got Office 365 and can use Filter functionality (if you don't have it, I advise you see if you are able to, its' got some wicked new functions like sort, sortby, unique etc.).

**Screenshots**

*Data tab*
[image: Source data - nothing special here, just for reference]

*Full_Questions*

[[image: Application of Filter function in Full_Questions Sheet2]

You didn't ask for this, but in case you make use of the filter function here it is for your convenience sir!

```
=FILTER(Data!F1:F500,Data!A1:A500=TRUE)
```

And the one you've been waiting for....☺

*FGD - Pop tab: with your function*
[image: Highlighting your function]

(after correcting the extra space issue in "3 FGD - Pop" filer (at source and in the function itself for consistency)

Function in question:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Full_Questions!$A$1:$A$10,SMALL(IF(Full_Questions!$C$1:$C$10="3 FGD - Pop",ROW(Full_Questions!$A$1:$A$10)),ROW(1:1))-1,1),"")
```

*FGD - Pop tab: with Office 365 "Filter" method*

[image: Highlighting parsimonious "Filter" function]

Function:

```
=FILTER(Full_Questions!B1:B3,1*(Full_Questions!C1:C3="3 FGD - Pop"))
```

Comment: Paragraph that is likely to be edited out: I'm not allowed to say "*I like the function construct you've used - i.e. the combination of index/small etc. to bring back unique index/match results - great initiative*" because it'll be edited out on account of not being 'robotic' enough in our replies (so will repeat this self-same sentiment in my comment below - ha!).

Comment: (fyi - you should include the {} array enclosures around each of your functions - as you did originally, and apply this cell by cell to avoid other errors - I may have missed these out when replicating your functions but didn't encounter an error as this looks like it only crops up when there is a False in one of the cells in column A of Data tab...)